# Error when applying summ() to date in R

Tags: r

When I try to use summ() or dotplot() on a Date value, I get the error:

```
do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct”
```

Basic example code:

```
date1 = as.Date("1970-01-01")
dateList = date1 + (0:3)
summ(dateList)
```

with the output described above.  Same thing happens when I use ISOdate or ISOdatetime to create the Date.  I have the epicalc library on the search path.  Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

What package does the 'summ' function belong to? It looks like it expects objects of the class POSIXct. You might try:

```
date1 = as.Date("1970-01-01")
dateList = as.POSIXct(date1 + (0:3))
```

Does this solve the problem? If not, it looks like the package epicalc is no longer on CRAN. What is it you are trying to do? Maybe there is another package that can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Strangely the same error pops up.  Actually I'm working through an epicalc book, but I'll just skip the section.